# NSUserDefaults iOS String Storing Error

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to store the value of an label in a NSUserDefault key `prevmode` but when it doesn't appear to be storing and when trying to recall after it says in debugger `Invalid CFStringRef`.

The code to store is

```
//Check for previous mode 
NSUserDefaults *defaults;
NSString *prevmode;
prevmode = passLength.text;

[defaults setObject:prevmode forKey:@"prevmode"];
```

and to recover is

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults;

NSString *prevmode;

prevmode = [defaults objectForKey:@"prevmode"];
```

Comment: What does the debugger say when you are _storing_ the value? And if you are using strings, might as well use setString:forKey and stringForKey:

Comment: setString doesn't exist? Then debugger only says when I said invalid CFStringRef

Comment: Just being a stickler for the details... you do have an actual non-nil reference to a userDefaults object, right? i.e. NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: Nope :P But I do now. and it works. Do you want to phrase that into an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Sorry, setString doesn't exist, but stringForKey should be used to retrieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expressed in the comments above, we need a valid pointer to an instance of NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setValue:` and synchronize after setting to defaults. Upon retrieving use `valueForKey:`

To save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:prevmode forKey:@"prevmode"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And to retrieve:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"prevmode"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Object for key is fine, and synchronise does not need to be called manually except in very rare cases.

Comment: @jrturton is right, however I don't downvote as `synchronize` is *the* problem in this situation.

Comment: `synchronize` isn't the problem. Not defining defaults properly was.

Comment: @H2CO3 overuse of synchronise is cargo cult programming. From the docs: Discussion
Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

Comment: Good find! I didn't notice it. I wouldn't even have thought that somebody would make such a stupidly trivial error...